# Excel VBA: How to write column name with commercial at "@" in it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out how I should deal with a named column in `myTable` which contains a commercial at (`@`) in its name, e.g. `active @ mail`. This code is supposed to print the column number in the Immediate output window:

```
Sub teststring()
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveSheet.Range("myTable[active @ mail]").Column
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

but it fails. Using `.Range("myTable[active" & Chr(64) "& mail]")` fails as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
s = ActiveSheet.listobjects("myTable").listcolumns("active @ mail").Range.Column
```

See also https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e  for how to escape special characters

So:

```
s = ActiveSheet.Range("myTable[active '@ mail]").Column
```

will also work.

`@` has a special meaning in structured references, so you can't use it in a column name without escaping it with `'` (a single quote)